# How make Yesod.Auth.Email display an error when an email is already registered?

Tags: haskell, authentication, yesod, email-validation

I found out when I try to register an email on RegisterR which already exists, instead of displaying an error message, that the user already exists, it sends an an email confirmation request to the given email address, just like if I asked for a password reset.

After going through the sources, I found out that `registerHelper` checks if the email exists, and if it does, it sends a verify email even if it's already verified.

```
-- [...]
    mecreds <- lift $ getEmailCreds identifier                           
        registerCreds <-                                                 
            case mecreds of                                              
                Just (EmailCreds lid _ _ (Just key) email) -> return $ Just (lid, key, email)
                Just (EmailCreds lid _ _ Nothing email) -> do            
                    key <- liftIO $ randomKey y                          
                    lift $ setVerifyKey lid key                          
                    return $ Just (lid, key, email)                      
                Nothing                                                  
                    | allowUsername -> return Nothing                    
                    | otherwise -> do                                    
                        key <- liftIO $ randomKey y                      
                        lid <- lift $ addUnverified identifier key       
                        return $ Just (lid, key, identifier)

        case registerCreds of
            Nothing -> loginErrorMessageI dest (Msg.IdentifierNotFound identifier)
            Just (lid, verKey, email) -> do
                render <- getUrlRender
                let verUrl = render $ verify (toPathPiece lid) verKey
                lift $ sendVerifyEmail email verKey verUrl
                lift $ confirmationEmailSentResponse identifier                                         
-- [...]
```

Source: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.3.1/docs/src/Yesod-Auth-Email.html#registerHelper

Since `registerCreds` is a `Just` when the email exists and it has a key, it sends the verify email again to the user, whiche he/she can use as a password reset link.

My questions are:

1. Why does it work this way? This basically makes registering an already existing email address equal requesting password reset. I'm sure it has a good reason, and it makes me wonder if I'm using `Auth.Email` correctly.
2. `Yesod.Auth.Email.postRegisterR` gets called immediately when the request arrives - where do I have a chance to check that the email address already exists, and inform the user?

**EDIT**: It turned out I was looking at the source of a much older version: I updated the question. In `yesod-auth-1.4.3`, this code is in `registerHelper`, not in `postRegisterR`.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing it on #yesod, this is probably a bug, so I filed an issue on it:
https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/948